# Can an iOS push notification be selected to show up only in the notification center?

Tags: ios, notifications, push

I am using iOS push notifications. Can you selectively set whether a push notification appears:
a) only as an alert / dialog box
b) only in the push notifications center
c) both

Or is there no way of controlling this?

I recognize that on the client side users can opt out. Assume for the purpose of the excercise the user has left the device on the default settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a fullproof way to do this since the end user can always change how they want them displayed in the Settings -> Notification Center.